# Questionable electric work

Tags: electrical, light-fixture, exhaust-fan

My bathroom light is connected to the same switch that runs my exhaust fan.  The switch doesn't go all the way up without an extra bit of a push and then sometimes when the switch is completely off the fan will continue to run long after it has been programmed to. Once it ran all night. Tonight I went back in to the bathroom having left something, and the fan was still running as it normally woul but as soon as In opened the door the bathroom light blinked like someone had touched the switch which I didn't have a chance to.

Comment: I would suggest this sounds like a faulty switch - not questionable work...

Comment: you can get a new switch for under $1USD, sounds like it's worth that step.